# Where does Oracle Java Mission Control store settings on Windows?

Tags: jmc

I am using v5.5 on Windows from JDK v1.8.0_60.  Where are connections and settings stored?  I cannot find on my disk nor registry.

(Yes, I am aware of `File -> Export...` to save settings to file.)

## Update

I tried to find the source code online, but I cannot find it.  If I had the source, it would be simple to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<USER_HOME>.jmc\5.5.0.metadata.plugins

For example C:\Users\klara.jmc\5.5.0.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.prefs is where the connections are stored.

The source code for JMC is not part of the OpenJDK project, it's Oracle internal.

Comment: Note: For Java 8, System property `user.home` now match the env var `%USERPROFILE%`.

Comment: Connections seem to be stored in `\.jmc\$VERSION\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings\com.jrockit.mc.rjmx.prefs` by default. Current versions of JMC are simply Eclipse-based apps and therefore support relocating those directories: `"jmc.exe" -configuration "%APPDATA%\Eclipse\Java Jmc\configuration" -data "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Eclipse\Java Jmc"`